# BIRT Dynamic Image Not Rendering on Report

Tags: image, dynamic, reporting-services, report, birt

I have a BIRT report design with a dynamic image (URL is specified through the data set, image formats tried - .png, .bmp). When running the report from our application on Windows, we get the following message instead of actual image:

[image: Error when the Report is Rendered on Browser]

The same problem occurs when including the image with a fixed URL - even though the image is displayed and loaded in the Report Designer, it's not rendered in the report generated from our application. Again, this happens only on Windows.

I have tried adding the Image in the following way: [image: Adding the Image through Data-Set in Dynamic Way]

The only way I managed to get the image into a rendered report was through embedding it (hard-coding the image ) into the report design file, which is not suitable as the image has to be dynamic.

Step which I followed

1. First I created a Data source and data set to retrieve image from the database.
2. Then I have used the image to create a dynamic image by creating data binding.
3. When I try to view the report using BIRT Viewer, I am not able to view the image in the report.

System Information: 
Windows 8.1,

OpenText Analytics Designer 
Version: 4.6.0
Build id: v20160406

Any help in fixing this issue is greatly appreciated. We are doing this work for a non-profit and this a last missing piece in the report.

Answer (score 1):

If the dataset contains only the URL to the image, you should use the URI option in the image properties window you displayed. There you can also select a javascript expression and choose the column from the table.

obviously the URL should be directly available from the system generating the report.